# Extracting strings starting with symbols and combining with others from a text using python

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a file with lots of URL and ordinary text together
Example:

```
'http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#Reference http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#Informal ACADEMIC type http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#school ACADEMIC type'
```

and I'd like to get:

```
'Reference Informal ACADEMIC type school ACADEMIC type'
```

I tried

```
substr1 = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", text1)
```

which does part of the job, but I don't know how can I extract these parts I want and combine them with the other words in the text. Essentially, I have to get rid of the URL and the "#" symbol. Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it around; remove the urls:

```
re.sub(r'\bhttps?://[^# ]+#?', '', text1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text1 = '\bhttp://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#Reference http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#Informal ACADEMIC type http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#school ACADEMIC type'
>>> re.sub(r'https?://[^# ]+#?', '', text1)
'Reference Informal ACADEMIC type school ACADEMIC type'
```

The expression looks for anything that starts with `http://` or `https://`, and removes that anything after that is not a hash or space, including an optional hash.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! It works fine. If I have more symbols that I don't want, for example parenthesis or brackets, how can I add this to your solution?

Comment: @user2725174: You'd have to be more specific about what you mean by that. That said, I'd probably attack `(..)` with a different regular expression applied before or after this one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#Reference http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#Informal ACADEMIC type http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2011/benchmarks/101/onto.rdf#school ACADEMIC type'
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'#(.*?)(?=https?:|$)', s))
'Reference Informal ACADEMIC type school ACADEMIC type'
```

Explanation : http://regex101.com/r/dV5uR2